# android jni ndk-build----------> undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, undefined-reference

android jni ndk-build---------->the error is:
undefined reference to `std::allocator::allocator()'

i have created a Application.mk under project/JNI/
with "APP_STL := gnustl_static"

so, any ideas, why undefined reference.

the environment is ubuntu10.4, and THE NDK is r5b,

Comment: Can you post a copy of your full Android.mk file?

Comment: @keven I think you should indicate what is your build environment: in windows or linux? And which version of NDK do you use?

Comment: the environment is ubuntu10.4, and THE NDK is r5b,

Answer (score 0):

You need to guarantee that "libgnustl_static.a" is set on the end of your libs, since it seems that they depend on it:

Example:

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += <system/your libs>
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -L$(ANDROID_NDK)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi -lgnustl_static
```

I add the same issue and overcome it with this...